# import XML to Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

What would be the fastest, easy, and quickest way to import an xml data to a database table in Oracle 10g database? What tool should I use (if possible free)?

The XML will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<badges>
  <row Id="82946" UserId="3718" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.923" />
  <row Id="82947" UserId="994" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82948" UserId="3372" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82949" UserId="3893" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82950" UserId="4591" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82951" UserId="5196" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82952" UserId="2635" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82953" UserId="1113" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
  <row Id="82954" UserId="4182" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" />
</badges>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you importing this file into?

See this question on stackoverflow: [Oracle: loading a large xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/998055/119634)

You can use [SQL*Plus with some PL/SQL to import XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998055/oracle-loading-a-large-xml-file/1000331#1000331) into your DB.

Comment: I actually just saw that post last night... I don't know how I can put it inside the directory

Comment: @equinox: You would create the directory Object in Oracle, then move the file in said directory using your operating system.

Comment: I have created a directory in Oracle.. I don't know how to move the file using the operating system.. this is a remote database that I have.. I only have IP address of the host name, username, and password

Comment: @equinox: the directory object points to a directory on the server itself. You must upload your file on the server somehow: this is a server-side method, not a client-side one.

Comment: So maybe I should use FTP to transfer the file to the server?

Comment: @equinox: yes, if you can upload your file via FTP to the server you could use this method